# Increment a value of state object

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to update the days value inside the state object each time and increate it's value by one

```
const [leap, setLeap] = useState({state: false, days:0})
```

So i tried doing it like that but that did not help

```
setLeap((prevState)=> ({...prevState, days: days++ }))}
```

Comment: You probably want `days: prevState.days + 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `days` key from the prevState for incrementing. Do as follows:

```js
setLeap((prevState)=> ({...prevState, days: prevState.days + 1 }))}
```

Answer (score 3):

Destructure `days` out of the previous state, and assign `days + 1` to the new `days` state:

```
setLeap(({ ...prevState, days }) => ({ ...prevState, days: days + 1 }))}
```